# form field that is acting out of line (literary)

Tags: css, wordpress, forms, hebrew, background-position

I got a form in the following URL http://netaimg.co.il/%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%A7%D7%A9%D7%A8/ (Hebrew)

whenever someone clicks the "name" tag (the right most one, I've added a picture with the name field highlighted) while using Google chrome the field disappears.

I've noticed that there is a background-position property being added (which I didn't specify).

I'm using "Contact form 7" for WordPress on this site, any help will be greatly appreciated.

[click here for the image](http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/img/51cbdf229e6fe4-57941005)

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem, but am unable to do so. The field remains visible and I can enter text. I'm using Chrome version 30.0.1599.101 on Mac OSX. What version of Chrome are you using?
PS. Just saw that this was a pretty old question, so might not be relevant anymore...

Answer (score 0):

What I notice is than when I click on any of the inputs, the cursor is outside of the text box. It looks like it's because the width of the `.texttab` is wider than it's parent. BUT, if you apply `box-sizing: border-box` to the `.texttab` class. And add some padding, the issue seems to be resolved.